# githubのpull requestでmerge pull requestが表示されない。

Tags: github

pull requestからマージをする際にmerge pull requestボタンを押下するのですがずっと読み込み中になっており表示されません。普段はすぐに表示されます。PCからchrome、edge、スマホからsafariで確認しましたがいずれも同じ状態です。何かアカウントの設定に問題があるのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 開発者ツールにて確認したところ、以下のURLで500エラーが発生していました。
https://github.com/組織名/リポジトリ名/pull/81/partials/merging

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
現象が発生していたリポジトリに個人とチーム両方で所属した状態になっており、個人の所属を削除したところ表示されるようになりました。